# Angular Heroes Tutorial part 1 display nothing

Tags: angular, typescript

I follow the [Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) of Angular to learn it. However, after I create the project, generate the component, modify the HTML, nothing displays on the page, not as expected.
[image]
Can someone solve it? Thanks a lot!

Here are my codes

[image]

**heros.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heros',
  templateUrl: './heros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heros.component.css']
})
export class HerosComponent implements OnInit {
  hero="WindStorm"
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**heros.component.html**

```html
<h2>{{hero}}</h2>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<app-heros></app-heros>
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HerosComponent } from './heros/heros.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HerosComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {HerosComponent} from './heros/heros.component'


const routes: Routes = [{path:'', component:HerosComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Nothing displays on *what* page? *Are* you running `ng serve`?

Comment: of course, I run it

Comment: I am pretty sure there are some insightful errors in the browser console that would help.

Comment: no error in the console...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the way you are routing.
Your app.component.html should look something like this

```js
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The following line basically replaces the router-outlet tag with an instance of the Heroes Component:

```js
const routes: Routes = [{path:'', component:HerosComponent}];
```

Comment: nothing special. Just some warning. `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gfbliohnnapiefjpjlpjnehglfpaknnc/content_scripts/purify.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: well thats weird, and still only a white page?

Comment: yep. Only the `title` parameter.